# Optimal language to develop with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, boo

I would like to ask you all about the Unity framework and programming. Unity supports three different languages; Boo, C# and Unityscript. Say you were new to programming and developing on OS X.

What is the best language to learn and use alongside Unity to create games?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's a matter of taste. All 3 languages are fully capable. It's also worth mentioning that performance-wise there is no significant difference.

So, which one? You'll have to choose for yourself.

Perhaps this would help:

C#:

- pros:

  - well known, easy to find people who know it
  - strict (find mistakes during compile time)
  - usable code bits may be found online, even outside Unity's context
- cons:

  - why so serious?

UnityScript (not really JavaScript):

- pros:

  - easy to learn quickly
- cons:

  - not strict (find mistakes late - only during run-time)

Boo:

- pros:

  - beautiful syntax (pythonesquely clean)
  - strict (find mistakes during compile time)
- cons:

  - not many people use it (so if you're hiring...)

Answer (score 0):

For me, a web developer, Javascript was easiest to use. I use C# when I need to, but Javascript is fastest for me and I don't notice any performance hits.

You can check out this thread on the Unity forums for choosing a language to work with:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/18507-Boo-C-and-JavaScript-in-Unity-Experiences-and-Opinions

Comment: I use (decent) statically typed languages where I can so I don't go insane. Any "performance" over a dynamically typed counterpart is just a bonus.

Comment: Sorry for adding a comment to a rather old topic, but with my experience with unity, I have found JS and C# to be good for different purposes. C# (being statically typed) is great for most programming, but GUI programming in Unity is a lot easier in JS.